# Setting up multiple EC2 instances and multiple subdomain under one parent domain in AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I am developing a set of frontend webapps (for instance vaadin or angular) and backend RESTful services. Each frontend webapp will consume one or more of these backend services. I want both webapps and services to be secured over https.

Now, I want to register a single domain, say mydomain.com, and deploy the backend services such that they are available at
service1.api.mydomain.com, service2.api.mydomain.com etc. The frontend apps should be available at webapp1.mydomain.com, webapp2.mydomain.com etc.

I need to be able to setup two or more EC2 instances for the services, and the same for the webapps. For instance, service1 may be running instance A, service2 on instance B, and webapp1 on instance C, and webapp2 on instance D.

**How do I configure this setup in AWS Route 53?**

Since there is a limit to the max number of Elastic IPs (max 5) that can be allocated for one AWS account, I suppose separate public IPs for all the EC2 instances **is not a solution**, since I will be having more than 5 such subdomains.

**I hope you can provide a practical example configuration with two services and two webapps.**

Answer (score 2):

You can submit a request to get the Elastic IP (EIP) limit increased for your account.  Small increases (e.g. from 5 to 10) should be fairly quick and easy to obtain.  Larger increases should be obtainable if you can justify it to AWS support.

https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/case/create?issueType=service-limit-increase&limitType=service-code-vpc

If you're open to using path-based routing instead of subdomain based (e.g. `mydomain.com/app1` and `mydomain.com/app1/api`) or a mix of the two (e.g. `app1.mydomain.com` and `app1.mydomain.com/api`), you could look at using an Application Load Balancer (ALB).  You would need one ALB per subdomain used.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html

*Note: I expect subdomain-based routing to be available with the ALB in the future, but it hasn't been released yet.*

ALBs could be cheaper than using Classic Elastic Load Balancers (ELBs), but if you're not using the load balancing functionality at all, EIPs may be your best bet since they're free when attached to a running instance.

Comment: That is the approach I took to solve my problem.But instead of ALB, I ended creating a new EC2 instance, installing apache server server on that, and set it up as reverse proxy. That's because I havent really started looking so much deeper into ALB and other services in aws, and know apache server from before.